# Angular 4 Observables Chaning Subscribers - Fired Two times

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-observables

I have a strange problem while using Angular 4 Observables.

I have created a ServiceProxy.ts that manages all my HTTPS calls for my app

```js
@Injectable()
export class ServiceProxy 
{
     
            private  base_url = 'https://localhost:8443'; 
            


            constructor (private  http:Http) {}
        
            public Request(route:ServiceRegistry, data : any , protocol:HttpProtocol)
            {
                
                let url : string = this.FormURI(route);
                let headers = new Headers();
                this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);

                if(protocol==HttpProtocol.get)
                {
                  
                    return this.http.post(url , data , {headers: headers})
                                .map(this.extractData)
                                .catch(this.handleError); 
                }
                else
                {
                  
                    
                    return this.http.post(url , data , {headers: headers})
                                .map(this.extractData)
                                .catch(this.handleError);
                }
            }
}
```

Now I go ahead and INJECT this ServiceProxy class in every SERVICE which needs an HTTP calls

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService
{

    constructor(private proxy:S.ServiceProxy){ }
    attemptLogin(d:L.LoginAuth): Observable<any>
    {
            let r:S.ServiceRegistry =S.ServiceRegistry.STAFF_LOGIN;
            let p: S.HttpProtocol = S.HttpProtocol.post;
            return this.proxy.Request(r,d,p);
    }
}
```

Once that is done. I call the authentication service from my component

```js
this.authService.attemptLogin(payload).subscribe(response =>
          {
              alert("Subscription Received");
              if(response.status==R.STATUS.OK)
              { 
                  this.HandleLogin(JSON.stringify(response.data));
              }
              else
              {
                  this.HandleFailedLogin();
              } 
          });
```

**Problem is - The subscription function is being called two times instead of just once.**

I understand, Promise would be a better fit here as this is just one HTTP call , however I want to standardize the interface with Observables and hence not considering Promises

Comment: Try to create working example using plunker. You can use [this starter](https://plnkr.co/edit/ulPZB1OQwkoFpbderRPk?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Observable Chain is not proper, it's broken in `AuthenticationService`.

Modify `AuthenticationService` class

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService
{

    constructor(private proxy:S.ServiceProxy){ }
    attemptLogin(d:L.LoginAuth): Observable<any>
    {
            let r:S.ServiceRegistry =S.ServiceRegistry.STAFF_LOGIN;
            let p: S.HttpProtocol = S.HttpProtocol.post;
            return this.proxy.Request(r,d,p).map(
                    (data) => {
                          return data;
                     }
                   ).catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```